# I have a "non zero exit code (101) issue

Tags: python, pycharm

I installed Python 3.7.2 64 bit for Windows, and I also downloaded the embedded files. I also downloaded Pycharm.

When I tried to create a project in pycharm I got a `non zero exit code(101)` error.

The command output is

`{unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Chana Riva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.2\helpers\packaging_tool.py" list'}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the down left corner there's a way to choose the correct interpreter. Check it, for me was the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You username has a space in it. You need to change it.

Problem: C:\Users\**Chana Riva**\AppData   will throw the error

Fix: C:\Users\**ChanaRiva**\AppData  will work

I'm not sure why but that fixed mine.

Do not rename your Windows username folder directly or you will screw the whole system.  Create another account or reinstall you OS if all else fails.